# Need to sign and zipalign apk project for android marketplace

Tags: android, google-play, eclipse-adt

I'm new here and have been reading through most of the similar questions but can't find the help I'm looking for.

We have an adroid app that has been developed by a third party(outsourced) and when I tried to upload it onto Google Play it says the file needs to be zipaligned. As we weren't involved in the development of the app we can't seem to get this sorted.

I have imported the apk file into eclipse but it doesn't let me export it as an android project - it just doesn't seem to recognise it!

Any help is greatly appreciated this is driving me mad now!

Answer (score 2):

command "zipalign 4 yourAppname.apk"  , or ask the developer to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, but when I enter the cmd it says 'zipalign is not recognised as an internal or external command'

Comment: Run it as Android-SDK\tools\zipalign

Comment: Thanks, the path to my zipalign folder is "c:\program files(x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools\zipalign" however I am still getting the command error saying 'C:\Program' is not recognised?

Comment: If you get 'zipalign' is not recognized as an internal or external command, the path to tools is incorrect.See it carefully

Comment: Apologies that what I meant. I don't think I have the adb command set up?

Comment: My PATH file is: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin    Should this be changed to the zipalign directory

Comment: where is your .apk file located? are you sure you making a correct reference to your .apk file?

Comment: Well the .apk file was just emailed to me so it is just saved on my desktop - should it be located somewhere else? (Sorry I have never worked with apps before) Is the PATH correct?

Comment: tell me exact path of your .apk file

Comment: First follow the correct path to zipalign tools in your sdk directory, second enter this command, zipalign -f 4 C:\Desktop\oca-androiddv1.apk C:\Desktop\ZipAlignedApp.apk

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected my file PATH to C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files(x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools\zipalign  But I am still getting 'zipalign is not recognised'

Comment: why are u writing zipalign in your command, it would be as simple as C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files(x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools

Comment: Sorry I have amended the PATH and it still gives zipalign is not recognised error

Comment: I have now managed to run the zipalign command  zipalign -f 4 C:\Desktop\oca-androiddv1.apk C:\Desktop\ZipAlignedApp.apk but it then says unable to open oca-androidv1.apk as zip archive? Any suggestions? thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Try Changing location of your .apk and destination where the zipaligned file would be stored , but do it carefully, provide the correct path ,NOTICE: zipalign will not create directories for you. If it still doesn't work fine, I'll wait for someone else to answer your question :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help I'll try changing their location now! Fingers crossed

Comment: It worked thank you!! But now when I try to upload it says 'you uploaded an apk that was signed in debug mode!! :(

Comment: App Signing is one of App's developer's issues.. Now how would it be signed if you have received an .apk file(attached with an email) ..!!!

Comment: I thought so!! Will send it back to the developer! Thank you again!

Comment: No issue :) and yeah right, ask him/her to align it for you NOW!! :p